My Ubuntu is focusing on one core but using all cores
I don't know why, but the system monitor is showing that after few seconds my CPU4 is going to 100% then again normal, however the other CPU Cores are in their normal usage ranges. This is making my system slow. Is there any way to fix this problem?


Please use ˝top˝ or similar command to see what command is using the CPU.
